# PHP memory leak when working with image

Tags: php, memory-leaks, gd

I'm having a bad time trying to work with an image with PHP.
The image is well ... big. It is a high definition picture (36MP resolution) for a total size of 23Mo.

I'm doing certain things on this picture, like resizing it or transforming it to greyscale.

The problem is, when I'm looking the memory usage using htop on a terminal, I can see that apache is using memory (a little more than 140Mb) but is not releasing it when image processing is over.

I deleted each image processing functions one by one and now have only those 3 simple lines, but the leak is still there :

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring( file_get_contents($imageFullPath) );
imagedestroy($image);
unset($image);
```

Does someone have any idea why ?

Thanks !

Jim

Comment: what is imageFullPath? and its content?

Comment: $imageFullPath contains the fullpath to the image on the disk ("/tmp/image.jpg" for example). Note that I also tried imagecreatefromjpeg :)

Answer (score 1):

it is a common memory problem in php . unset($image) is not deleting image from memory it only deletes link of data. try empty image like this .

```
$image = NULL;
```

Comment: do not use imagedestroy and unset. and try like this $image = " "; @jimouest2005

Comment: Yeah I alreay deleted imagedestroy just in case. Even with $image = " ";, the leak is still there @synan54